# Linking problem as I am making python module using OpenSSL + SWIG

Tags: python, linker, openssl, swig

I have a C file `dtls_udp_echo.c` in which I use SSL functions. I am trying to create a Python wrapper for this file using SWIG. I've done the following steps:

1) Created an interface file `udp.i`:

```
%module udp

%{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */

 #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
 #include "dtls_udp_echo.h"

%}

int THREAD_setup();

int THREAD_cleanup();

int handle_socket_error();

int generate_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int *cookie_len);

int verify_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int cookie_len);

int dtls_verify_callback (int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx) ;

void* connection_handle(void *info);

void start_server(int port, char *local_address);

void start_client(char *remote_address, char *local_address, int port, int length, int messagenumber);
```

2) Run the command `swig -python udp.i`.

3) Run the command `gcc -O2 -fPIC -c dtls_udp_echo.c  -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lcrypto -lssl`. The path to the include and library is correct, I checked it!

4) Run the command `gcc -O2 -fPIC -c udp_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.5 -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lcrypto -lssl`.

5) Run the command `gcc -shared dtls_udp_echo.o udp_wrap.o -o _udp.so`.

It seems to complete OK as no errors are reported. But, when I try to import the module, I get the following traceback:

```
>>> import udp
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
> File "udp.py", line 28, in <module>
>     import _udp ImportError: ./_udp.so: undefined symbol:
> SSL_get_rbio
```

Can anybody help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the OpenSSL library. Add it to your ld search path; see the `ldconfig(8)` man page for details.

Comment: Thank you, friend! But it didnot help! I added /usr/local/ssl/lib and /usr/local/ssl/inlude in ld.so.conf, make "sudo /sbin/ldconfig" and even make "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib". But I still have the same problem!!!!

Comment: Do you have another copy of OpenSSL on the system?

Comment: Yes, I have installed openssl in standart path /usr/local/ssl but before I installed openssl in folder where my .c file is located and then deleted.

Comment: I have just used strace and I guess that is the problem: